# extract index of observation in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors

a<-{1,2,5,6,7}

b<-contains mappings of above values as index of b

I want to extract index of 'b' when it matches value of 'a' e.g. if value 2 in 'a' matches value at index 8 in 'b', then would like to extract '8'

I am a newbie to R so is searching for solution

Comment: I think I know what you want but your example is pretty difficult to follow and thus is hard to provide you with an accurate solution.  I would suggest you provide us with a minimal reproducible sample that enables us to actual work with your problem in R.  so for instance for a [if it is a vector] you may want to use `a <- c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7)` as we can reproduce that.  As for `b` it's difficult to surmise what you have and therefor what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7)
b <- c(2, 3, 5, 9)

match(a, b)
```

Comment: sorry for the unclear question.  match() worked fine. Thanks!!